# Use for_each or accumulate to calculate frequencies

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been playing with a simple example using C++11 and some standard algorithms, and I'm not sure whether to use `std::accumulate` or `std::for_each`. The problem is to count letters in a word, so, for example, for an input of "abracadabra", you get

```
'a' => 5
'b' => 2
'c' => 1
'd' => 1
'r' => 2
```

My first cut was to use `std::accumulate`. The reason this seemed natural is that we're really accumulating a value (a set of frequencies). Also I've been doing some functional programming recently and `accumulate` seemed to be the natural translation of [folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) a list.

```
vector<int> charsInWord(const string& text)
{
    return 
        std::accumulate(text.begin(), text.end(), vector<int>(256),
            [] (const vector<int>&v, char c)
            { 
                vector<int> v2(v);
                v2[c]++;
                return v2;
            } );
}
```

However this solution seemed rather cumbersome and took a little while to get right. Moreover, even with the new `move` semantics I couldn't quite convince myself that there wouldn't be any unnecessary copying.

So I went for `for_each` instead.

```
vector<int> charsInWord2(const string& text)
{
    vector<int> charCounts(256);
    std::for_each(text.begin(), text.end(),
        [&] (char c)
        {
            charCounts[c]++;
        } );
    return charCounts;
}
```

This is probably easier to write and understand, and I certainly feel happier about its efficiency (although I miss the declarative, functional style of `accumulate`).

Is there any good reason to prefer one over the other in examples like these? From the comments and answers so far, it seems like if the value I am accumulating is non-trivial, say an `stl` container rather than an `int`, I should always prefer `for_each`, even when I am really "accumulating".

---

For the sake of completeness, the rest of the code to get this to compile and test is below

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric> // accumulate
#include <algorithm> // for_each 

using std::string;
using std::vector;

#include <iostream>

// ... insert code above ...

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const vector<int> charCounts = charsInWord("abracadabra");
    for(size_t c=0; c<charCounts.size(); ++c) {
        const int count = charCounts[c];
        if (count > 0) {
            std::cout << "'" << static_cast<char>(c) << "'" << " => " << count << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `accumulate` version is inefficient. I don't know why you expect move semantics to apply, but they don't. You will be creating a new vector at each iteration. I don't understand the issue you have with `for_each`; it's practically the same code.

Comment: @Dave thanks, I thought at the very least that the value copy on the `return v2` might get optimized out. I'm just starting playing with C++11, and have only got a "layman's" view of what some of the concepts are. I need to do some in-depth work.

Comment: if you don't see an rvalue reference (`&&`) or `std::move`, there's no move semantics. The returned value may have been optimised pre-C++11, since optimising a return-by-copy was allowed in C++03. Anyway, even if it did move, that isn't free. You're better off doing things like in your other example, where you have a persistent object which you update.

Comment: @Dave: Move symantics kick in slightly more that that. `rvalue references` are moved. So return values from a function will be moved rather than copied. But in this situation no real difference.

Comment: Range based for ftw: `for (char c : text) ++charCounts[c];`

Comment: @LokiAstari: Language lawyer thinks you meant to say _rvalues_ can be moved. Which is not the same thing as rvalue references. You are correct in saying that moves can happen without an obvious `&&` or `std::move` (but there would still be a non-obvious `&&` hidden away in a class, `std::vector` in this case). In this case it doesn't help because there is still a copy happening inside the lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would not have written the accumulate like that:

```
vector<int> charsInWord(const string& text)
{
    std::vector<int> result(256); // One version never copied.

    int count = std::accumulate(text.begin(), text.end(), 0,
            [&result] (int count, char c)
         // ^^^^^^^^^ capture
            { 
                result[c]++;
                return count+1;
            } );
    // Might use count in the log file.
    return result;
}
```

But If I am doing that it seems just as easy to use for_each()

```
vector<int> charsInWord2(const string& text)
{
    vector<int> result(256);
    std::for_each(text.begin(), text.end(),
        [&result] (char c)
        {
            result[c]++;
        } );
    return result;
}
```

I don't see anything wrong with the for_each version.

But why not go with a simple `for()` loop?

```
vector<int> charsInWord2(const string& text)
{
    vector<int> result(256);
    for(char c : text) {result[c]++;}
    return result;
}
```

There was some discussion about using std::map in the comments (and then in some deleted questions). Just to capture that here and expand.

We could have used `std::map<char,int>` instead of `vector<int>`. The difference are:

`From: @Dave` std::map has O(ln(n)) lookup time while vector is O(1). So there is a performance consideration. Note also that the fixed cost for map will be higher than vector. Though this is small but worth noting.

`From: @Dave` std::vector has a fixed size of approx 256*4 (1024), while map has a size of approx 12*number of unique characters (min 12 max 3072). So no real space consideration in modern machine. But may be worth optimizing on phones and such.

`From: @POW` The third point is the std::map makes printing the result much easier as you do not need to check for empty values.

Vector print

```
for(size_t c=0; c<charCounts.size(); ++c) {
    if (count > 0) {
        std::cout << "'" << static_cast<char>(c) << "' => " << charCounts[c] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Map Print

```
for(auto loop: charCounts) {
    std::cout << "'" << loop.first << "' => " << loop.second << "\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks, is it fair to say that when the sum being accumulated is non-trivial (e.g., as in this case, an stl container rather than a basic type), that you wouldn't do the accumulation of the sum via the 3rd arg of `accumulate` -- rather you would update the sum via a side-effect as you have done in your answer (this comment mirrors my edit to my question).

Comment: @TooTone: Added one more option.

Comment: thanks, a `for` loop would be appropriate here, as it beats `for_each` when the whole range is used (I also had another example where I was only looking at a subrange).